# Django fixtures. JSONDecodeError

Tags: django, django-admin, django-fixtures

I've a Django project and I want to add test data to database. When I make syncdb like this

```
python ~/django/foo/manage.py syncdb
```

After tables are installed I've got an error

```
Problem installing fixture '~/django/foo/shop/fixtures/initial_data.json': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

My model is here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to = "img/")
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, 
        blank = True
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, blank = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```

My fixture is this:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "shop.image", 
        "fields": {
            "slug": "", 
            "file": "img/8_m.jpg", 
            "title": "1"
        }
    }
]
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wild guess... maybe your fixture file is saved as a unicode file???  Try to open it in the simplest text editor you can, or run

```
hexdump ~/django/foo/shop/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

and make sure the first character in the dump is `5b` not `fe` or something.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and this seems to be the problem. Now what can I do about it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: One simple way is `cat > ascii_fixture.json` and then copy/paste the file's contents and then control-D to finish it.  For huge files or windows google "convert unicode text file to ascii".